# Why am I getting Unexpected token F in JSON at position 4

Tags: reactjs

I am currently following a food recipe tutorial and in this tutorial the tutor used the fetch method to get recipes. But in my console I am getting an unexpected response which is Unexpected token F in JSON at position 4, though he used double quote to wrap the url, it didnt work for me so I used a backtick for it

```
     class App extends React.Component {
     state = {
     recipes: [],
     url:
        /* I used a backtick to enclosed this url key */
    `https://www.food2fork.com/api/search?
    key=d2da2ee197824412ca0cd3df68139fdf`

      };

     async getRecipes() {
       try {
    /* This is the line the console is telling me the error is from 
       */
  const data = await fetch(this.state.url);
  const jsonData = await data.json();
  this.setState({
    recipes: jsonData.recipes
     })
       } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    }
 }

  componentDidMount() {
   this.getRecipes();
 }

    render() {
  console.log(this.state.recipes)
  return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <RecipeList />
    <RecipeDetails />
  </React.Fragment>
  );
    }
     }
    export default App;
```

I expect the url call to push some result in the empty array

Comment: The request returns "403 FORBIDDEN"

Comment: Yes, "403 FORBIDDEN" WAS THE RETURN IN CONSOLE

Comment: You'll probably need to get a renewed/valid `key` which will likely solve the problem